# tcpdump to only print urls

Tags: python, tcpdump

Is there a way to do

```
tcpdump -i lo -A
```

and have it print all urls, any connections made?

I have done:

```
sudo tcpdump -i lo -A | grep Host:
```

which works great. But I was wondering if there are options to do the same in tcpdump

Finally, is there a way to do this in python without using a sys command or Popen/subprocess

Comment: tcpdump cannot filter using the content of the packages, you could improve your performance by only dumping those packages for `incoming TCP connections to your HTTP port`.

Comment: Also, as HTTP doesn't transfer the URL requested in a straightforward manner, it will be slightly harder to pick out of a tcpdump feed - you have to combine the `Host` header and the `GET` or `POST` line to get the full URL...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use scapy the sniff function and use regex or grep

```
import scapy
tcpdump = sniff(count=5,filter="host 64.233.167.99",prn=lambda x:x.summary())
print tcpdump
```

change the filter for your filter text :)

or maybe you want to save the traffic and see it in wireshark

```
wrpcap("temp.cap",pkts)
```

Comment: Is it possible to sniff for a period of time and not a given count.(start sniff) do stuff. (stop sniff) Also, it is important that we record everything on interface lo.

Answer (score 4):

tcpdump cannot filter based upon the content of the packets (no deep packet inspection) as it only uses pcacp-filter. 
You could improve your performance by only dumping those packages for `incoming TCP connections to your HTTP port`.

```
tcpdump -i lo -A tcp port 80
```

TCPDUMP python: use [Pcapy](http://corelabs.coresecurity.com/index.php?module=Wiki&action=view&type=tool&name=Pcapy)

Another option is to use [tshark](https://serverfault.com/questions/84750/monitoring-http-traffic-using-tcpdump)

Comment: "tcpdump cannot filter based upon the content of the packets (no deep packet inspection)". Using `-vv` gets you pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

What you want to use is libpcap which is the packet capture library which tcpdump uses. There is a python wrapper for this which can be found [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pylibpcap/).

You can, in python, then build any filtering that you want on top of the filtering already provided by pcap/tcpdump. Then display this filtered output (or whatever it is you want to do in your python script).